# Parameter Sniffing in SQL Server 2022

Tags: sql-server, performance, parameter-sniffing

I'm working on the SQL Server performance area and I want to know that is the **Parameter Sniffing** problem resolved in SQL Server 2022 completely ?

What **trace flags** are useful in this area ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not.

See this article Brent Ozar wrote about it.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2022/08/pspo-how-sql-server-2022-tries-to-fix-parameter-sniffing/

> Small problem: we still have sniffing. Try running it for, say,
> Reputation = 3 and review the actual query plan ... then free the
> cache and see the difference.
>
> Medium problem: direct equality searches only. The PSPO implementation
> is more of a down payment than a full payment. It only works for
> equality searches, not range searches. One of the most common
> parameter sniffing problems is the date range issue: queries with
> start & end date parameters, like this.
>
> Large problem: monitoring software is doomed. If you look closely at
> the sp_BlitzCache screenshots, there’s a huge, massive, giant,
> unbelievably big new problem.... SQL Server can no longer tell where
> the query came from. It’s like every running statement is suddenly
> dynamic SQL with no parent... If you think that’s bad, there’s no way
> to join to the underlying statements. That’s not just bad, it’s poor.
> Really, really poor.